# How to use command output (ls) into other command's input (sox)?

Tags: ls, command, input, sox

I have a folder with multiple .wav files that I am trying to concatenate in order but I think that I am too inexperienced with bash commands to do this as efficient as possible. You see, I don't know how to use a files content as input for a command:

I get all the file names in correct order with:

```
ls *.wav | sort -V > script
```

Script:

```
ep1-s1.wav
ep2-s1.wav
ep3-s1.wav
```

I add ' \' after each line to use in the command

```
lam script -s " \\" > script2
```

Script2:

```
ep1-s1.wav \
ep2-s1.wav \
ep3-s1.wav \
```

I delete the last ' \':

```
sed '$ s/.$//' script2 > script3
```

Script3:

```
ep1-s1.wav \
ep2-s1.wav \
ep3-s1.wav
```

And now I want to use the content of that file for the `sox`, like:

```
sox ep1-s1.wav \
ep2-s1.wav \
ep3-s1.wav output.wav
```

How can I achieve this?

Now, there is probably a way to do this in one command, but I couldn't figure out how piping works like that: if you know how to, I would really love to know!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `sox`.  Could you give an example of the command you would like to run and we can help you build a script to generate that command?

Comment: that's probably a job for [xargs](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/findutils/xargs.1.en.html)

Comment: @A.B Wow, you're totally right. I was completely overthinking this whole thing. I guess I learned a few new things from it, but this was way easier than I thought: thanks!

Comment: depends if you need to sort in versioning order, that's why I deleted the comment. but look at xargs if you really need this sort -V

Comment: Yea, I just noticed, that's not in the correct version ordering, I thought that it was.

Comment: @DavidKing I want to run a command like this: `sox ep1-s1.wav ep2-s1.wav ep3-s1.wav output.wav` but I want to create the `ep1-s1.wav ep2-s1.wav ep3-s1.wav` part dynamically, depending on the files in the directory and in order using: `ls *.wav | sort -V > script`

Comment: How about just `sox *wav`?  Given your example filenames and normal Linux locale settings this would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I mentioned in a comment, if you don't need version sorting (`sort -V`), you can simply do `sox *wav`.  In Linux, `*wav` will undergo filename expansion, resulting in a list of alphabetically sorted filenames.  This is affected by your locale settings, particularly `LC_COLLATE`, which you can Google for more info.

If you need `sort -V`, the right way to handle this is with null terminated strings and arrays to handle filenames with spaces and other special characters.  This script will put the output of the `sort` command into an array and run `sox` with this list.

```
#!/bin/bash

unset wav_files

while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
   wav_files+=("$file")
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*wav" -print0 | sort -V -z)

if (( ${#wav_files[@]} == 0 )); then
   echo "No wav files found"
else
   sox -- "${wav_files[@]}"
fi
```

This might be more than you were expecting, but it's good practice ;)

Answer (score 0):

*If and only if* your filenames are "nice", and don't contain whitespace or special characters (esp. glob characters), the easy way out is to run `sort` in a command substitution:

```
sox $(printf "%s\n" *.wav | sort -V) output.wav
```

The `printf` here works to put newlines (`\n`) after each filename.

<sub>(As usual, an unquoted expansion like that will break if the filenames have spaces or tabs (they'll be split in two after the `$(...)` is expanded); or newlines (they'll be split in two before the `sort`); or glob characters (`*?[]`, they'll expand to any matching file names). So don't do that if you don't know the filenames are nice enough. See e.g. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting and  [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)</sub>

Answer (score -2):

Why not try :

```
sox `ls *.wax | sort -V`
```

Comment: Because https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs